# cannot install apps from app store ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade

tried installing chromium web browser from the store , its starts to install but stops in the middle. Also installed the update but could not apply it

Comment: This is way too concise to be answered.  At least post the commands you used and results you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try using command line instead to install the chromium web browser. I have found that using this is much more reliable, and if something goes wrong it's easier to find out why it isn't working.

You install apps using the apt-get install command. You will need to run the command as superuser though in order to install any app though. Thus, using

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Should do the trick. You will need to enter your password. To open terminal in Ubuntu, you can use the hotkey Ctrl-Alt-t

Answer (score 0):

The app store(Ubuntu Software Center) is buggy at 16.04 . If you press download button in Ubuntu Software , it starts but suddenly stops. You should install old version of Ubuntu Software Center or find a way to install it from terminal.